# Default include path Glibc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, include-path

I'm working on a set of libraries for a project, and we'd like to make them easy to include. Because of this, we put the libraries in /usr/lib/skywalker and the headers in /usr/include/skywalker. In every program, we include the libraries as #include , for example.

The problem comes when we want to cross-compile with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc (the final platform is arm). It seems to not get /usr/include as a default include path, and it doesn't compile. I've been searching on the web, and tried several parameters for the compiler, and I could only find the libraries directory.

How can I know the default path for the headers in a certain compiler? How can we solve this problem in an easy way (this libraries will be used by another group of developers)?

Comment: I'm not a C programmer but I'm guessing it's because when you cross-compile for a different platform, you need different headers, so it can't use `/usr/include`. The standard old-fashioned way to solve this is using autoconf, automake and make; a newer way to solve it is with CMake, which is a lot easier to use. I don't know if they support cross-compilation though, but I'd be surprised if they didn't.

Comment: Try `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v -c somefile.c`, look for `#include <...> search starts here:`.

Comment: @n.m.: I've been looking for this. I tried every informational command in the compiler, and nothing worked. So easy then! I can solve everything now. Thank you very much.

Comment: /usr/include is a terrible path for a cross compiler, you risk inadvertently including host headers, and that is no fun to debug.

Comment: @nos: now I know that the header path for the cross-compiler is /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc/include, and I'll be using those. I won't be mixing host an cross-compiler to avoid crashes

Comment: I suggest you use `-L` and `-I` in your `Makefile` and tell users of your library to set theses accordingly. From what I know GCC-based cross-compilers when installed in some path, by default look into path relative to its `bin/` and you shouldn't install your libraries in e.g. `/opt/crosscompiler/bin/../shared/lib` path.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this alias:

```
alias mygcc='gcc -I /whatever/'
```

Also, you can use environment variables `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`; more on it:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables

Comment: I was looking for a more elegant solution. The comment from @n.m. helped me a lot to find a solution.